# node-gyp install error when trying to use npm

Tags: npm, node-gyp

When I try to use npm for installing johnny-five with the package serialport in it I get a bunch of errors. I believe that this is a problem with node-gyp so I downloaded python 2.X and it still wont work.
my log:
http://pastebin.com/SMjaXekd

Answer (score 0):

You say you downloaded Python 2.X but what version did you actually download and install?  According to node-gyp's [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) they recommend version 2.7.3 for Windows machines:

```
On Windows:
Python (v2.7.3 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)
Make sure that you have a PYTHON environment variable, and it is set to drive:\path\to\python.exe not to a folder
```

You can check what python version your machine is using by running `python -V`.  You may have more than one version of python installed but this command will tell you which version is being used by your machine.  If you have version 2.7.3 installed but that's not what `python -V` reports then you can configure npm to use version 2.7.3 by running `$ npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7` prior to running `$ npm install johnny-five`.